# ListView Not Clickable or LongClickable

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom `listview` but can't manage `Click` and `LongClick` on that
this is `XML` of `ListActivity` :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    >
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@id/activity_main_l2"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" 
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="@color/main"
                  android:layout_gravity="center" 
                  android:gravity="bottom"
                  android:visibility="visible" 
                  android:id="@id/activity_main_search_layer">
        <EditText android:id="@id/activity_main_search_text"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_margin="5dp" 
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:background="@drawable/message_field"
                  android:hint="@string/Search_hint" 
                  android:textColor="@color/textFieldColor"
                  android:layout_gravity="center" 
                  android:maxLines="8"
                  android:paddingLeft="10dp" 
                  android:paddingTop="5dp"
                  android:paddingRight="10dp"
                  android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                  android:textSize="14dp"
                  android:singleLine="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:divider="#00000000"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:listSelector="#00000000"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:longClickable="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
<include layout="@layout/header1" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/include"/>
<include layout="@layout/draver_menu" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:id="@+id/include1"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

and this is `XML` of `ListRow` :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:background="#fafafa"
android:gravity="end"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@id/list_row_rl"
android:padding="5dp"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="0" 
        android:focusable="false" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:focusable="false" 
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:padding="3dp" android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:foregroundGravity="center" 
            android:focusable="false" 
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

            <QuickContactBadge
                android:id="@+id/quickContactBadge1"
                android:layout_width="52dp"
                android:layout_height="52dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="52dp"
                    android:layout_height="52dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_frame" 
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center" 
                    android:focusable="false" 
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_counter" 
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" 
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:id="@id/list_row_number_of_new_sms_layer"
                android:visibility="invisible" 
                android:focusable="false" 
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Numberofsms"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="420"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
                android:autoText="false"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp" 
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@id/list_row_click_button"
            android:background="#fafafa"
            android:focusable="false" 
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@id/list_row_click_layer">
        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:focusable="false" 
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="68dp"
                     android:id="@id/list_row_l1"
                    android:gravity="right|top" 
                    android:layout_gravity="left|top" 
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|left|top"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" 
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

                    <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="35dp" 
                            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                            android:gravity="left|top"
                            android:focusable="false"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
                        <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/ContactName"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.60"
                            android:text="@string/ContactName"
                            android:textColor="#666666"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:typeface="sans"
                            android:textAlignment="gravity"
                            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:gravity="left|top"
                            android:phoneNumber="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
                            android:maxHeight="40dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:focusable="false" 
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
                        <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                android:id="@id/list_row_count" 
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
                                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="left|top" 
                                android:gravity="left|top"
                                android:textSize="16dp" 
                                android:focusable="false" 
                                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/LastSMS"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:text="سلام امروز روز خوبی است."
                        android:textColor="#aeaeae"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:phoneNumber="false"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:linksClickable="true"
                        android:autoLink="web"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left" 
                        android:gravity="center|left" 
                        android:focusable="false" 
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                            />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp" 
                    android:background="#f34323" 
                    android:focusable="false" 
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:layout_gravity="top" 
                android:gravity="top" 
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="68dp"
                    android:foregroundGravity="left|top"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                    android:gravity="center|top" 
                    android:focusable="false" 
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/list_row_draft_text"
                        android:id="@+id/list_row_draft_textview"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:textSize="8dp" 
                        android:textColor="#ff00ac"
                        android:visibility="invisible"
                        android:focusable="false" 
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Date"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="5:45"
                    android:textColor="#aeaeae"
                    android:textSize="11dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="right" 
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:focusable="false" 
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" 
                          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_height="2dp"
                          android:background="#f34323"
                          android:id="@+id/linearLayout" 
                          android:focusable="false" 
                          android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and in `ListActivity` :

```
    list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            some code...
        }
    });

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                some code...
        }
    });
```

but non of these listener get `Click` or `LongClick`
just `LongClock` on one of the `TextView`(android:id="@+id/ContactName") work

The `Adapter` :

```
 public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<BoxInfoObject> implements Filterable {
 public Adapter(Context c, int resource, int layout, ArrayList<BoxInfoObject> d) {
    super(c, resource);
    this.c = c;
    mOrigionalValues = new ArrayList<BoxInfoObject>(d);
    mObjects = new ArrayList<BoxInfoObject>(d);
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public LinearLayout L0;
    public TextView NAME, LAST, NUMBEROF, DATE, DRAFT, NUMBEROFNEW;
    public QuickContactBadge Badge;
    public LinearLayout L1, L2;
    public int position;
    public ListView list;
}

public void add(BoxInfoObject object) {
    mOrigionalValues.add(object);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public Filter getFilter() {
    if (mFilter == null) {
        mFilter = new CustomFilter();
    }
    return mFilter;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mObjects.size();
}

public BoxInfoObject getItem(int position) {
    return mObjects.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position2, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.list_row, null, false);
        holder.L1 = (LinearLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.list_row_l1);
        holder.L0 = (LinearLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.list_row_rl);
        holder.DATE = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.Date);
        holder.Badge = (QuickContactBadge) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.quickContactBadge1); // thumb image
        holder.list = (ListView) parent.findViewById(R.id.list);

        ,...

        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

    holder.position = position2;
    BOX = mObjects.get(holder.position);

    int APIlevel = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (APIlevel > 11)
        new load(holder, position2)
                .executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);
    else
        new load(holder, position2).execute();


    return vi;
}

private class load extends AsyncTask<ViewHolder,
        Void, Void> {
    private final int p;
    private ViewHolder h;
    private String holder_NAME_string;
    private int holder_l2_visible;
    private String holder_NUMBEROFNew_string;
    private BoxInfoObject BOX;
    private QuickContactHelper QCH;
    private QuickContactBadge Badge;
    private String holder_Date;
    private inboxQuickAction quickAction;
    private String holder_text;

    public load(ViewHolder holder, int p) {
        this.h = holder;
        this.p = p;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        if (h.position == p) {
            h.DATE.setText(holder_Date);

            if (holder_NUMBEROFNew_string != null)
                if (holder_NUMBEROFNew_string.length() > 0)
                    h.L2.setVisibility(holder_l2_visible);
                else
                    h.L2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            else
                h.L2.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            h.NUMBEROFNew.setText(holder_NUMBEROFNew_string);

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(ViewHolder... arg0) {
        try {
            h.DATE.setTypeface(h.font);
            h.NUMBEROF.setTypeface(h.font);
            h.NAME.setTypeface(h.font);
            BOX = mObjects.get(p);
            holder_text = BOX.getSmses().get(BOX.getSmses().size() - 1).getMessage();
            holder_Date = MakeBox.StringDate(c,
                    BOX.get().get(BOX.get().size() - 1).getMyDate(), H);
            if (BOX.getPNs().size() == 1)
                QCH = new QuickContactHelper(c,
                        BOX.getPNs().get(0), BOX.getOPNs().get(0));
            else
                QCH = new QuickContactHelper(c);
            try {
                QCH.BadgeImage2(h.Badge, false);
                Badge = QCH.getbadge();
                Badge.setMode(ContactsContract.QuickContact.MODE_SMALL);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            if (BOX.getPNs().size() == 1) {
                holder_NAME_string = QCH.getname();
                if (holder_NAME_string == null) {
                    Badge.setImageResource(R.drawable.unknown);
                } else {
                    if (QCH.holder.tId == null || QCH.holder.tId == 0)
                        Badge.setImageResource(R.drawable.personal);
                }
            } else {
                Badge.setImageResource(R.drawable.multiplus);
            }

            int nons = BOX.getNNew();
            if (nons > 0) {
                holder_l2_visible = View.VISIBLE;
                holder_NUMBEROFNewSMS_string = nons + "";
            } else {
                holder_l2_visible = View.GONE;
                holder_NUMBEROFNewSMS_string = "";
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

any suggestion ?

Comment: your codes are just fine , but we need more codes to find out what happens.

Comment: What do return from the following callbacks from your adapter:
>getView() >getItemId() >getCount(). Share your code for your adapter

Comment: Do you want to enable the user to perform any action on a specific view in the row (like edit text,...) or do you just want to know whether he pressed or longpressed the whole list item?

Comment: ok it seems the reason that LongClick work on one TextView is  android:phoneNumber="true" tag , when i remove this , the LongClick not call

Comment: remove following attributes                                android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"                 form from your list row (from every View) and try again

Comment: Thanks Ali but not work

Comment: try removing all of the focusable/clickable attributes of the ListView, none of that should be necessary and maybe it's not properly delegating those touch events to it's children (the rows).

Comment: i know the problem is notifyDataSetChanged(); in adapter, when i remove notifyDataSetChanged(); the all other focus will work well, but if i remove that , my list view not update well